# Slicing or aggregating data frame based on certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, aggregate

I have a dataset which contains latitude and longitudes. I want to take those rows in data set where distance is less than 1 km. For entire distance calculation part I have written a function which will return true or false. So I want to consider those rows on which this condition is applied.

It may be through lambda function but not sure how as I think lambda always return a value might be.
If conditions can be applied for column values but think that is not enough in my case.

Any leads are appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information about your dataset? Does he contain two columns, one for lat and one for long?

If you want to apply your func to the dataset you can use `map`
Somth like this:

```
func = lambda x: x > 0
data = [1, -1, 3, -2]
result = list(map(func, dataset))
```

After that you will get:

```
result = [True, False, True, False]
```

Or you can vectorize your processing with use of `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

func = np.vectorize(lambda x: x > 0)
data = np.array([1, -1, 3, -2])
result = func(data)
```

It will fastest one solution.

If u give more information about structure of dataset i will try to fix your problem

Comment: Hey thanx for response . Yes I have two columns one for latitude and longitude. I am willing to pass those as parameters to the function for each iteration of the data frame. If the funnction returns true than it should be there in data set otherwise no.